# Get request with Many-to-Many association in Hibernate seems to lead to infinite loop

Tags: angular, spring, hibernate

I have a many-to-many relationship in Hibernate, and when I try to retrieve data with @GetMapping, I get an error.

On the backend it is hard to find the error message, since I cannot scroll far enough up on the console (increasing the buffer on IntelliJ did not help).

On the front-end (in Angular) where I try to retreive the data, I get a 200 OK message with an error and no data. The error is `SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 82277 of the JSON data"` and the text is the following:

```
"[{\"speciesId\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attributesId\":1,\"species\":[{\"speciesId\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attributesId\":1,\"species\":[{\"speciesId\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attributesId\":1,\"species\":[{\"speciesId\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attributesId\":1,\"species\":[{\"speciesId\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attributesId\":1,\"species\":[{\"speciesId\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attributesId\":1,\"species\":[{\"speciesId
```

but continuing for a lot longer, and after that:

```
{\"timestamp\":\"2019-01-12T14:49:20.913+0000\",\"status\":200,\"error\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.model.Species[\\\"attributes\\\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.model.Attributes[\\\"species\\\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.model.Species[\\\"attributes\\\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.model.Attributes[\\\"species
```

Again continuing for a lot longer than this.

The StackOverflowError and long row of the same text leads me to believe that in  @GetMapping, Hibernate ends in an infinite loop.

The two linked classes are Attributes and Species.

**Attributes:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Attributes")
public class Attributes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int attributesId;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable (
            name = "Species_Attributes",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "attributesId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name= "speciesId")}
    )
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    Set<Species> species = new HashSet<>();

    @NotNull
    @Column
    String attribute;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    String value;

    public void addSpecies(Species s) {
        this.species.add(s);
        s.getAttributes().add(this);
    }

    [...]
}
```

**Species:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Species")
public class Species {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int speciesId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "species")
    private Set<Attributes> attributes = new HashSet<>();

    @NotNull
    @Column
    String species;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    String description;

    public void addAttribute(Attributes a) {
        this.attributes.add(a);
        a.getSpecies().add(this);
    }

    [...]
}
```

**The Get Request:**

```
@GetMapping("/speciesdb")
    Iterable<Species> showSpecies(){
        return speciesService.findAll();
    }
```

I can put data in my database. I have checked all tables, including the species_attributes table, and they all contain the correct data. If a species has no attributes yet, retreiving data works as expected without errors. It is only when I add an attribute that I get this error.

**Edit:**
If I remove the `addSpecies()` and `addAttribute()` functions and clear and refill the tables, I no longer get the error. Now, if I `get` the species, the list of attributes is empty.

Comment: you should not add to both sets, (in `addXXX` methods) ..I think this causes the stackoverflow, it is sufficient to fill only 1 side of the manyToMany.

Comment: I later tried a few things to do with the addXXX methods, but they would either result in no attributes, or the infinite cascade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your Species and Attribute are linked to each other which may cause infinite loop sometimes. For example ,your object graph may look like the followings:

[image]

Assume you use Jackson to serialise to JSON , you can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to break the cycles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Attributes")
public class Attributes {

    [.....]
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("attributes")
    Set<Species> species = new HashSet<>();

    [...]
}   

@Entity
@Table(name="Species")
public class Species {

    [....]
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("species")
    private Set<Attributes> attributes = new HashSet<>();

    [...]
}
```